# Browser extension / userscript to add an icon to itemize a list in an answer or question on Stack Exchange

Tags: web-browser, stack-exchange

I sometime wants to copy paste a list to a StackExchange question or answer:

```
Connect to the remote computer with IP address and password.
Once connected, press function key F8 and click "Options"
Click "Load / Save"
Click "Save As"
Choose a name which suits you and click "Save"
At the VNC Viewer : Warning about storing the password, click "Yes".
```

and I need to add the `-` at the beginning of each item of the list:

```
- Connect to the remote computer with IP address and password.
- Once connected, press function key F8 and click "Options"
- Click "Load / Save"
- Click "Save As"
- Choose a name which suits you and click "Save"
- At the VNC Viewer : Warning about storing the password, click "Yes".
```

I'm looking for a browser extension or userscript to add an icon or shortcut to do this at once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Userscript

Source code: https://gist.github.com/ComFreek/9879093

Disclaimer: I am the author, however, I've created the script specifically for this question.

### Compatibility

Browsers:

- Chrome 33
- Firefox 27

StackExchange sites:

- `*://stackoverflow.com/*`
- `*://meta.stackoverflow.com/*`
- `*://pt.stackoverflow.com/*`
- `*://serverfault.com/*`
- `*://superuser.com/*`
- `*://askubuntu.com/*`
- `*://stackapps.com/*`
- `*://mathoverflow.net/*`
- `*://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/*`
- `*://*.stackexchange.com/*`

Note: the extension will not appear in the 'improvement' mode when reviewing suggested edits. This is due to the AJAX loading of the editor. Support may be added if requested.

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

### How to install (Chrome)

1. Download the userscript
2. Open the extension page in Chrome
3. Drag the file onto the page
4. Confirm the installation
5. Ready

### How to install (Firefox)

1. Download & install the [Greasemonkey extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
2. Download the userscript
3. Drag it onto any Firefox window

Comment: Awesome, works great. I use `// @match          http://stackoverflow.com/*  // @match     http://*.stackexchange.com/*` to support all SE websites (FYI [match vs include](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts)).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Sadly that doesn't support all SE websites. There are odd ones like SuperUser, ServerFault, StackApps, and then there's the very odd Area51. I've probably missed some.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thank you for the suggestion! Please see the update. I've fixed some serious bugs, improved the support for more sites and removed the jQuery dependency.